# ¿Puede un método o función devolver un ArrayList en C#?

Tags: c#

Sencillamente eso, ¿puede un método o función devolver un `ArrayList`?

¿Si es posible podrian darme un ejemplo de su sintaxis?

```
public ArrayList[] altareco (string var1,string var2)
{
    Lrecorridos.Add(var1);
    Lrecorridos.Add(var2);

    return Lrecorridos; 
}
```

Comment: Si puede, y francamente, no es algo que sea muy dificil de investigar o intentar por tu propia cuenta. ¿Lo has intentado? Lo que sí te diré es que te sugiero evitar la clase `ArrayList` (sin genéricos) a favor de la clase `List<T>` (con genéricos) para mayor "type safety".

Comment: lo intente ahi agrego como lo hice, pero tengo un problema al devolverlo y no puedo usar list debido a que solo puedo usar cosas que haya visto...

Comment: Como agregastes tu codigo, te puse una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu ejemplo puede ser corregido a (nota que quité el `[]` y instancié un `ArrayList` antes de hacer los adds):

```
public ArrayList altareco (string var1,string var2)
{
    var Lrecorridos = new ArrayList(); 
    Lrecorridos.Add(var1);
    Lrecorridos.Add(var2);

    return Lrecorridos; 
}
```

Pero toma en cuenta que al usar `ArrayList`, no hay ninguna garantía en cuanto a los tipos de los elementos en la lista, lo que puede causar problemas en su uso.

Hoy se prefiere si usas la versión genérica usando la clase `List<T>`.

Ejemplo:

```
public List<string> altareco (string var1,string var2)
{
    var Lrecorridos = new List<string>(); 
    Lrecorridos.Add(var1);
    Lrecorridos.Add(var2);

    return Lrecorridos; 
}
```

Comment: Si muchas gracias estaba intentado llegar a lo mismo por que pense que era como un arreglo comun, tenia un problema de sintaxis ahi, como te decia gracias por el tip de List pero no puedo usar cosas que haya visto, pero gracias igualmente de nuevo!! marcado y puntuado!!!